# How to configure Build In POS printer with android PrintService

Tags: android-studio, printing, android-service, android-print-manager

I have PAX A920 and i am trying to print receipt from chrome.
I wan to configure printer service in android for print receipt from my build in printer
I have write printer service for local printer and its is showing in preview, but I don't know how to configure build in printer.
This is code for local printer

```
final List<PrinterInfo> printers = new ArrayList<>();
            final PrinterId printerId = generatePrinterId("Pax-printer:built-in");
            Log.e("the", "the local printer id is " + printerId);
            final PrinterInfo.Builder builder = new PrinterInfo.Builder(printerId, "POS Printer", PrinterInfo.STATUS_IDLE);
            PrinterCapabilitiesInfo.Builder capBuilder = new PrinterCapabilitiesInfo.Builder(printerId);
            capBuilder.addMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A6, true);
            capBuilder.addMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A3, false);
            capBuilder.addResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("resolutionId", "default resolution", 600, 600), true);
            capBuilder.setColorModes(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR | PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME, PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR);
            builder.setCapabilities(capBuilder.build());

            printers.add(builder.build());
            addPrinters(printers);
```

I am also getting Document object

```
final PrintDocument document = printJob.getDocument();
```

[image]

but I can not utilize this document to set in customer printer, my customer printer accept payload of text and bitmap.
here is code for printing from PAX A920

```
PrintPayload payload = new PrintPayload();
             payload.append(bmp).align(Alignment.CENTER);
             print(payload);
```

How can i convert this `document` object to bitmap?
How can i configure build in printer with android PrintService

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not too late.
If you take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72363832/how-to-access-the-file-associated-with-printjob-object-in-an-android-printservic), you would find some helpful code and insights into the way I've solved this very issue you were/are having. My solution was some kind of union between the code in this [Zaki50 PrintService](https://github.com/zaki50/MyPrintServiceProject), and this [Thermal Print Service Repo](https://github.com/serrexlabs/thermal-printer-service). If it is helping, you could comment to that affect, and I will post the behaviour from the answer to my question here as well, so that you would accept it as an answer.