# (Android) Is it possible to convert a PrintJob into Bitmap and pass it on to a POS printer?

Tags: java, android, printing, bitmap, point-of-sale

Is it possible to convert a PrintJob to a bitmap? I have an Android 7.1.1 POS and its internal thermal printer is not recognized by any application (it also doesn't work bluetooth), but it can print using its API (which I have), with tips from users @Zap! and @Commonsware I managed to create a service with the PrintService that adds a custom printer, now the applications can recognize this custom printer, however I am not able to pass on what should be printed to the POS printer, since it only supports simple things like bitmaps, text, tables, bar codes, qrcodes, RAW data...

Applications try to print receipts in image format (JPEG or PNG), would it be possible to extract these files from PrintJob and convert to Bitmap? [I found a topic about converting PrintJob to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72363832/how-to-access-the-file-associated-with-printjob-object-in-an-android-printservic) but the ByteBuffer.NEW() function doesn't exist anymore, which made it not work