# Android Get HTML content from PrintDocument as String

Tags: android, printing

I'm writing [Print Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrintService) android app for my web app. When my web app opened from google chrome android device, my print service app must be able to do print job. So I implement this from documentation :

```
@Override
    protected void onPrintJobQueued(PrintJob printJob) {
         final PrintDocument document = printJob.getDocument();
         ........
    }
```

As I know, that document is object to print from page of google chrome. So I need the HTML content from that page as String (like : Hello, This is My Web App) but I still cannot get the HTML as string. I use this snippet but when do print to logcat, it have weird symbols.

```
 final FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(document.getData().getFileDescriptor());
 final byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
 StringBuilder datax = new StringBuilder("");
 try {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader ( in ) ;
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader ( isr ) ;
    String readString = buffreader.readLine ( ) ;
    while ( readString != null ) {
        datax.append(readString);
        readString = buffreader.readLine ( ) ;
    }
    isr.close ( ) ;
 } catch ( IOException ioe ) {
    ioe.printStackTrace ( ) ;
 }
 out.println(datax.toString());  // Weird Symbols
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72392941/6819340?